# how to merge two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 dataframe posisi awal and fitnes

posisi awal

```
0
3
5
7
9
11
```

fitnes

```
0.3316353909828977
0.2961631571266477
0.2662361889631912
0.24311842459472494
0.2240267212016412
```

i want to merge these dataframes using this code:

```
local_best_baru=pd.concat([posisi_awal,fitnes],axis=1)
```

and the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Use `ignore_index=True` inside `pd.concat` as argument.

Comment: @SayandipDutta its not work

Comment: @SayandipDutta its not work

Answer (score 0):

maybe the index of `posisi_awal` and `fitnes` is not the same, try to use `.reset_index(drop=True)` first.

```
local_best_baru=pd.concat([posisi_awal.reset_index(drop=True),
                           fitnes.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```